# Processing user input string in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am writing a function that takes in a user entered string consisting of o's g's and c's only. I would like to make an if statement that says if string contains any other character besides these three (reading string from left to right), return false, or something like that. How do I go through the string as an array to do this?

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: This is not a free coding service.  Show your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
if (s[strspn(s, "ogc")] != 0) {
  /* s contains a character other than o, g or c */
}
```

`strspn(s, chars)` returns the length of the longest prefix of `s` containing only characters in `chars`. If `s` contains only such characters, that prefix is all of `s`, so the character at that index will be the NUL terminator.

If your string might contain a newline or other whitespace after the desired characters, you'll need to adjust the test accordingly.

See [man strspn](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) for more information.